# Call a "create" partial view in Index view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

I am new in MVC Asp.Net, I am working over a simple web application but I am trying to code it dynamically using Modals (To create a new record) but the issue is that when I call a partial view, the code does not save the information.

This is the HTML of the modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                @Html.Partial("View", new MyWebAppInMVC.Models.Question())
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the partial page:

```
@model MyWebAppInMVC.Models.Question

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Questions", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AddModal" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Question</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOfQuestion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfQuestion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfQuestion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" id="BtnSubmit" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
     @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")}
```

Here the controller

```
// GET: Questions/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Questions/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,Description,DateOfQuestion,Type")] Question question)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Questions.Add(question);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(question);
    }
```

It's actually very simple, however, the partial view does not save anything.
What's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add your controller code to the post please?

Comment: Sure, there you go.

Comment: if you set a breakpoint in your `Create` post action does it ever get hit? I'm guessing not because your form is posting to the `Questions` action.. or maybe you just haven't posted the relevant code it's kind of hard to tell. From what youve posted, it looks like your form using statement should be `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Questions", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AddModal" }))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where in your code you call the Create action of your controller?
I think you should use:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Questions", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "AddModal" }))
```

Comment: Super great! Thanks a lot!